# How to implement the animation effects of Material Design?

Tags: material-design

I'm very new to the concept, still trying to understand it. I was expecting google will provide something like bootstrap does, which bundled with CSS and JavaScript, let you realize the design by simply put some CSS class.

But it turns out on the material design homepage, the resources are all graphic files, so do we need to write our own JavasSript to apply the animation effect? And if everyone writes their own JavaScript, how can it be consistent? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you downloaded the wrong files. There is a JS file and a CSS file. You can view the demos here: https://material.angularjs.org, to see what is possible. It is similar to bootstrap, but using directives instead of classes (you need angular on your site as well)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.2/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

**Angular Material**, the library I have linked to is an implementation of material design using Angular JS. The team is supported by Google and many of the developers either work for Google now or did in the past, but I'm not sure if its an official Google product.

**Material Design** that you link to appears to be a react library, it links to this github which explains it, https://github.com/callemall/material-ui, but it is just using a different JS library to implement the components (React vs Angular). The page you link to in your comment appears to be a style guide of sorts. I don't see anywhere to get prebuilt css/js for it. The components appear to be the same as the ones in Angular Material though.

**Polymer** is a web component polyfill. It is so you can start building your own web components today, it is not a library of premade components. https://css-tricks.com/modular-future-web-components/

Comment: Thank you for the info. I was looking at http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html, I believe this is the official MD page, but it doesn't offer any CSS or JS for download. While I do notice there are some other material design sites, like http://material-ui.com/#/components/appbar  and https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/material.html#shadow-effect and the one you just gave me. But are these sites from google? What is the relationship and differences between them? I'm really confused.

Comment: So it seems there is no official installation bundle provided by google, is there? Google just provides some specifications and let people make their own design?

Comment: Yea I am not sure about an official implementation. I have used angular material on a few sites and it is very easy to use like bootstrap. I haven't used any other implementation of material design though

Answer (score 1):

The excerpt for of the tag you used in question answers your question:

> Material design is Google's guide for visual, motion, and interaction design across platforms and devices, introduced with Android 5.0 Lollipop.

Material design is a specification made by Google that defines how an applications UI and UX should be. It is not only meant for web application development. For example, Google material design is being use in Andriod  applications. So yes, we have to write custom code to implement the UI and UX for the technologies we are using. Luckily, there are many libraries out there implementing material design spec.

How can they be consistent? Well, that is what the specification is for. Whoever develops material design components should follow material design specification, if not - it is not material design.

Find more info: [material-design](/questions/tagged/material-design)

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers make good points, however here is a clearer answer to the OP:

The [Material Design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/) are just standards for everyone to follow regardless of the technology they're using (e.g. C++, Javascript or perhaps even print).

Up until recently, the only way to implement MD into your app was to use a 3rd-party library (there's many) or just manually tweak your design to meet the MD spec.

Google now has an official implementation, with downloadables, called [Material Components](https://material.io/components/). You can use it, or still choose from any one of the 3rd-party libraries.

MD libraries tend to fall into 3 groups:

1 Stand-alone MD libraries, using JS and CSS, with no framework dependencies. The official [Material Components](https://material.io/components) is one example.

2 MD libraries for popular JS frameworks like Angular, React, and jQuery. If your app is built around a framework, then it's probably best to use a MD library for it.

3 CSS-only implementations, which get you pretty far for visuals but have obvious limitations when it comes to interaction.

Google search yourself for "Material Design libraries" and you can find them.